# How can I control which duplicates are deleted?

Tags: regex, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have a list of duplicates that have different durations attached to it (in a Google Sheet):

```
Duplicate A - 2:21
Duplicate A - 2:21
Duplicate A - 3:30
Duplicate A - 4:00
Duplicate B - 2:04
Duplicate B - 6:00
Duplicate C - 5:32
Duplicate C - 3:43
Duplicate C - 2:32
Duplicate C - 9:00
```

What I would like to do is find all duplicates and only keep the one entry in each set (A,B,C) that has the longest duration.

So my list should look like this at the end:

```
Duplicate A - 4:00
Duplicate B - 6:00
Duplicate C - 9:00
```

What's the best way to achieve this? Regex? Formula?

Comment: Are these values in different columns?

Comment: yes, sorry for the late reply

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way you could do this is with a filter and `MAX()`:

Here is an example sheet I created to demonstrate this.
[image: ex]

In cell `D1` I have the formula

```
=filter(unique(A1:A), unique(A1:A)<>"")
```

And in cell `E1` I have

```
=iferror(max(filter($B$1:$B, $B$1:$B<>"", $A$1:$A=D1)))
```

The formula in `E1` would need to be dragged down the column (though someone else may have a better solution that doesn't require this).

Please let me know if you have any questions, or if this does not work for you.

Comment: hm I had to adjust your formula to account for a header row (so A2 instead of A1 and B2 instead of B1). The first formula seems to work correctly, however with the second formula I always get 0:00